# Track selection range change for NSTextField (cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, selection

Does anyone have any idea how I can track `NSTextField.currentEditor.selectedRange` value changes for `NSTextField`?

There is this wonderful thing `NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification`, it does exactly what I need, but it works only for `NSTextView`.

I've tried to play with KVC/KVO but I didn't get what I wanted. I assume I did something wrong.

I will try to explain what I need to achieve.

I have `NSTextField`, below I have a label where I want to put values from `NSTextField.currentEditor.selectedRange` of text selection above. In realtime, i.e. I want to update my label content continuously with selection length and start position from `NSTextField.currentEditor.selectedRange` while selecting area of text.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this "retired" article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html), the "field editor" designates the current text field as its delegate. Since the field editor is an [`NSTextView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview?language=objc) instance, we can implement any [`NSTextViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextdelegate?language=objc) method in our `NSTextField` subclass.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSRange selection = self.currentEditor.selectedRange;
  NSLog(@"selection = (location: %lu, length: %lu)", selection.location, selection.length);
}
```

Enjoy! ✌️

Answer (score 1):

`NSTextField` uses the field editor of the current window to do the actual text editing, and that is an `NSTextView`. To subscribe to `NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification` on that text *view*, you need to find out when your field gets keyboard focus and then ask it for its `currentEditor`.

Sadly, it seems `controlTextDidBeginEditing:` is never called, but you can override `becomeFirstResponder` to get the same effect (be sure to call super).

I can't find a good spot to unsubscribe though, as the text field only has keyboard focus for a split-second, and then loses it when it creates and activates the field editor NSTextView.

So in the end, what I'm doing is subscribing for the notification with a `nil` object when the view is created, unsubscribing in dealloc, and checking if `notification.object == self.currentEditor` in the notification handler and ignoring all others.

Comment: The `controlTextDidBeginEditing:` method is called once a change is made, which the docs mention here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextdidendeditingnotification

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `-windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:` on your `NSWindow` delegate and return a different field editor for the control(s) you care about, perhaps with the relevant `NSTextView` notifications set up just for that field editor.  Or, of course, you could return your own subclass of `NSTextView`, though that is probably unnecessary here.